how switch to new to tab and go back to the previous tab with selenium?
the question is simple. I have this products on a list, the result of a search. when it clicks on a button it goes to a new tab. My intention is simple: click on this product, focus on this new tab, scrap the information that I want and then close this new tab and goes back to the previous tab and so on in a loop. Here is how I'm trying to make it, but the program is simply ignoring it: it doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't do what I want, it doesn't even open a new tab.
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json
import logging
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re
from fpdf import FPDF
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver

precos = []
tamanhos = []
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    #options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxy}")    
    #options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #options.add_argument("disable-infobars")options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--verbose")
        #options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") 
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")    
data_planilha = []
precos_m2 = []

url_base = "https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/ceara/caucaia/bairros/caucaia/#onde=,Cear%C3%A1,Caucaia,Bairros,Caucaia,,,,BR%3ECeara%3ENULL%3ECaucaia%3EBarrios%3ECaucaia,,,/"
driver.get(url_base)
#driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class = 'header__nav-links']/li[2]/a").click()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
resultados = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class = 'results__main']" )))
quantidade_imoveis = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[@class = 'results-summary__count js-total-records']"))).text
quantidade_imoveis = int(quantidade_imoveis)
print(quantidade_imoveis)
try:
    botao_proximo = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title = 'Próxima página']")))

    while True:
        
        time.sleep(1)    
        imoveis = WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'results-list js-results-list']/div")))
        print("entrou")
        for index, value in enumerate(imoveis):
            driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            imoveis = WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'results-list js-results-list']/div")))

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", imoveis[index])
            time.sleep(3)


            tamanho = imoveis[index].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class = 'property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value property-card__detail-area js-property-card-detail-area']").text
            #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", tamanho)
           # tamanho = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//span[@class = 'property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value property-card__detail-area js-property-card-detail-area']"))).text
            print(tamanho)
            driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            preco = imoveis[index].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class = 'property-card__price js-property-card-prices js-property-card__price-small']/p").text
            preco_imovel = "".join(re.findall('\d+', preco))
            price = int(preco_imovel)
            links = imoveis[index].find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "property-card__labels-container js-main-info js-listing-labels-link")
            for link in links:
                
                link.click()
    
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
                driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')

                anuncio_ano = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'description__info-date big-space']/span[2]"))).text
                driver.implicitly_wait(20)
                driver.close()

                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) 

                
            #preco = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//div[@class = 'property-card__price js-property-card-prices js-property-card__price-small']/p"))).text
            size = int(tamanho)
            print(preco_imovel)
            precos.append(int(price))
            tamanhos.append(size)
            preco_m2 = price/size
            print(preco_m2)
            precos_m2.append(preco_m2)
           
            
            print(anuncio_ano)
            if("2024" in anuncio_ano):
                quantidade_2024 += 1

            
          botao_proximo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title = 'Próxima página']")
        valor = botao_proximo.get_attribute("data-page")
        
        
        if valor != "":
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', botao_proximo)
        else:
            break

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("última página")
tamanho_medio = sum(tamanhos)/quantidade_imoveis
preco_medio_total = sum(precos)/quantidade_imoveis
precos_m2_total = sum(precos_m2)/quantidade_imoveis
data_planilha.append({
        'URL': url_base,
        'Número de anúncios': quantidade_imoveis,
        'Preço Médio': preco_medio_total,
        'Tamanho Médio': tamanho_medio,
        'Preço Médio por m2': precos_m2_total,
        
        })
df_planilha = pd.DataFrame(data_planilha)
df_planilha.to_excel("catalogo_vivareal.xlsx")
print("salvou")
driver.quit()


Each property has a hyperlink to the detail page. You could explicitly GET that link, scrape the page then reload the original page.

I have checked your code by running it.
First, I eliminated try because it conceals some kinds of error.
Next, I added print('len(links) ',len(links)) and found it zero.
So I altered the line for links as,
links = imoveis[index].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class ='property-card__labels-container js-main-info js-listing-labels-link']")

and got the length of "links" as 1.
At the same time, the system gave the following message.
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\..\residence.py", line 71, in <module>
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

I don't know how the switch_to.window is effective. Instead, my method is to open another driver to look details of each item. This second driver is opened only once at the top of the program.
Url for each item can be got from the links (although it is singular) by href attribute.
